# Password cracker returning _Parent_proxy was 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a brute force password cracker using c++ however the following code keeps giving me this error(Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
_Parent_proxy was 0xCCCCCCCC)
i believe the error lies within the generate function as the code runs with that commented out. the code is also incomplete but it should run for the sha256 cracker, any help would be much appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "sha256.h"

//prototype functions
void Crack();
std::string Generate(unsigned int length, std::string s);
bool Compare(std::string sha256, std::string sha512, std::string md5, std::string PassHash);

const char PassChar[61] =
{
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
    'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
    'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
    'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',
    'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
    'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
    'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 
    '1' , '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
};


int main()
{

    std::cout << "Cracking Password \n";

    Crack();

    return 0;
}


void Crack()
{
    unsigned int stringlength = 1;
    const std::string PassHash = "BC98BB50E8094B2AC3CEB90BA2512587C0513CD294A07EFCFDCF467198DA6266";

    while (stringlength < 9)
    {
        //increases password length up to 8 characters

        std::string PassAttempt = Generate(stringlength, "");

        //Hashes password attempts
        std::string Sha256Attempt = "";
        picosha2::hash256_hex_string(PassAttempt, Sha256Attempt);

        std::string Sha512Attempt = "";

        std::string Md5Attempt = "";

        //Checks for a correct hash
        bool Collision = Compare(Sha256Attempt, Sha512Attempt, Md5Attempt, PassHash);

        if (Collision = true) {
            std::cout << "Password Cracked! \n Password = " << PassAttempt;
            return;
        }

        stringlength++;

    }
    std::cout << "Password Not Cracked: password may be too long, max 8 chars";
    return;
}


std::string Generate(unsigned int length, std::string s)
{
    if (length == 0) // when length has been reached
    {
        //std::cout << s << "\n"; // print it out

        return s;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 61; i++)

    {
        // Call generate again until string has reached it's length
        std::string appended = s + PassChar[i];
        Generate(length - 1, appended);
    }

}


bool Compare(std::string sha256, std::string sha512, std::string md5, std::string PassHash) {

    bool Collision = false;

    if (PassHash.compare(sha256)) {
        Collision = true;
    }

    if (PassHash.compare(sha512)) {
        Collision = true;
    }

    if (PassHash.compare(md5)) {
        Collision = true;
    }

    return Collision;
}
```

Comment: 'if (Collision = true)' should be 'if (Collision == true)'. But mainly learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: debugger didnt reach that far so i missed that one unfortunately

Comment: Visual Studio fills uninitialized variables with 0xCCCCCCCC in debug mode. It even names the variable in the message...

Comment: And note that [std::string::compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) returns 0 (false) when the strings are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has undefined behaviour:

```
foo.cc: In function ‘std::__cxx11::string Generate(unsigned int, std::__cxx11::string)’:
foo.cc:87:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Turn on compiler warnings in your compiler and read them.

Once you've done that and see that your code doesn't do what you intended think of why Generate can not generate all possible passwords and return them.

Comment: thanks, in my rush i evidently messed up the logic of my code